# Get an object parameter value inside a jQuery function inside an object's method

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have this:

```
function test1()
{
    this.count = 0;
    this.active = 0;
    this.enable = function () {this.active = 1;}
    this.disable = function () {this.active = 0;}
    this.dodo = function ()
                {
                    $("html").mousemove(function(event) {
                        // I want to get here the "active" param value;                 
                    });
                }
    this.enable();
    this.dodo();
}

instance = new test1();
instance.disable();
```

Let's say I want to check the active param of the test1 class in the commented place. How can I get it there ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want access to all the member variables of the higher scope, you just need to save the `this` pointer from that scope into a local variable so you can use it inside the other scope:

```
function test1() {
    this.count = 0;
    this.active = 0;
    this.enable = function () {this.active = 1;}
    this.disable = function () {this.active = 0;}
    var self = this;
    this.dodo = function () {
        $("html").mousemove(function(event) {
            // I want to get here the "active" param value;                 
            alert(self.active);
        });
    }
    this.enable();
    this.dodo();
}

instance = new test1();
instance.disable();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
this.dodo = function ()
            {
                var active = this.active;

                $("html").mousemove(function(event) {
                    alert(active);             
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call a function 'this' refers to the object the function was invoked from, or the newly created object when you use it together with the keyword new. For example:

```
var myObject = {};
myObject.Name = "Luis";
myObject.SayMyName = function() {
    alert(this.Name);
};

myObject.SayMyName();
```

Note in JavaScript there are multiple ways to declare, define, and assign fields and methods to objects, below is the same code written more similarly to what you wrote:

```
function MyObject() {
    this.Name = "Luis";
    this.SayMyName = function() {
        alert(this.Name);
    };
}

var myObject = new MyObject();
myObject.SayMyName();
```

And yet another way to write the same thing:

```
var myObject = {
    Name: "Luis",
    SayMyName: function() {
        alert(this.Name);
    },
};

myObject.SayMyName();
```

There are also several different ways to invoke a function.